# What is wrong with my code? I think it may be the header() command

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I run the below code, it clears the form and keeps me on the same page. I am wanting it to, on successful login, re-direct to home.php

I think there is a problem with my

```
header()
```

I've tried various different things here and have also read that the Location must be a http address, if this is the case, how do i make it point to home.php which sits in my root directory. Any ideas? also any other comments on the code would be appreciated.

```
<?php include_once("scripts/global.php");
$message='';
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $remember=$_POST['remember'];
    
    // error handling
    
    if( (!$email) || (!$pass)){
        $message = 'Please enter both fields';
    }else{
        
    //secure the data
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
        $pass=sha1($pass);
        
        $query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE email='{$email}' AND password='{$pass}' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error($link));
        $count_query=mysqli_num_rows($query);
        
        if($count_query == 0){
            $message='The information you entered was incorrect';
        }else{
            // start the sessions
            
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($link, $query)){
                $username=$row['username'];
                $id=$row['id'];
            }
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['id']=$id;
            
            if($remember == "yes"){
                // create the cookies
                setcookie("id_cookie", $id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
                setcookie("pass_cookie", $pass, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
            }
            
            header('Location: ./home.php');
        }
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login to Sweet Chain Fantasy 2022</title>
    <link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container center">
<h1>Login to Sweet Chain Fantasy 2022</h1>
    <p><?php echo("$message"); ?></p>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><br /><br />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes" checked="checked" />Remember me?<br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Login" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the info @tadman. Just starting on this project and this is useful. Small project for now and will adapt my code with your suggestions above.

Answer (score 0):

As the @tadman told you in comments, you really shouldn't build auth system for a production if you absolutely don't need to.
If, however, you are doing this for experimenting and learning then unless you have a custom server config, chances are that this will work for you

```
//relative link
header('Location: /home.php');
```

or this

```
//absolute link
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/home.php');
```

Comment: After a quick test I'm getting a similar result, the page just appears to refresh but doesn't re-direct to home.

Comment: @MattDrake check the network tab in code inspector. Could be that page is redirected  to home.php but is then redirected back (possibly because something is wrong with the session)